# Weak Topological Structure in Integral Dependence.

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A\subset R$ be commutative rings with identity. $x\in R$ is **integral over** $A$ if $x$ is vanished by some monic polynomial with coefficients in $A$. Define the **integral closure** $\mathrm{Cl}_R(A)$ of $A$ in $R$ to be the set of integral elements of $R$ in $A$. If we are only talking about the subrings of $R$ we abbreviate the notation as $\overline{A}$. $A$ is **integrally dense** in $R$ if $\overline{A}=R$. $A$ is **integrally closed** in $R$ if $\overline{A}=A$.

Note that we can generalize the defintion of integral closure to any subsets of $R$.

Here are some standard results using this notation: (Fix the ring $R$ so we suppose all other sets are subsets of $R$.) We have

> $(i)$ $A\subset \overline{A}$ for any set $A$.
>
> $(ii)$ $\overline{\emptyset}=\emptyset$.
>
> $(iii)$ $\overline{(\overline{A})}=\overline{A}$ for any ring $A$.
>
> $(iv)$ $\overline{A\cup B}=\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$ for any rings $A, B$.

So the integral closure of a special class of $P(R)$(namely the family of the subrings of $R$, but note that this family is not closed under unions, but we can focus on a chain of subrings instead) satisfies the Kuratowski closure axioms. I would like to know if this has been studied before.

For results relating to integrally dense we have:

> Let $A\subset B \subset R$ be rings. Then
>
> $(i)$ If $x\in \mathrm{Cl}_R(B)$ and $A$ is integrally dense in $B$ then $x\in \mathrm{Cl}_R(A)$.

This implies that

> $(ii)$ If $A$ is integrally dense in $B$ and $B$ is integrally dense in $R$, then $A$ is integrally dense in $R$.

Does all the above definitions and results have any significance in other areas?(like algebraic geometry or algebraic number theory, etc)

In the special case of ideals $\mathfrak{a}\subset R$. Radical ideals are closed.

Comment: Let $R=\Bbb C$, $A=\Bbb Z[\frac{1}{2}], B=\Bbb Z[\frac{1}{3}]$ then $A$ and $B$ are integrally closed subrings. In $\overline{A \cup B}$ we find for example the roots of the polynomial $x^2+\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{3}$ which are not contained in $\overline{A} \cup \overline{B}=A \cup B$.

Comment: @MatheinBoulomenos I reformulate the question and post it to mathoverflow. You are absolutely right-so I consider the case when we look at a chain of subrings, ordered by inclusion so that the union is again a subring. But we also need the chain to be compatible with the chain of closure of the subrings.